# AJax ignoring response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, if-statement, comparison

I'm running some ajax on my website to handle form submission, However, For some reason whenever I check the response from PHP, it ignores my handling and goes straight to the bottom.

```
//Login Form Submission
$('form.loginform').on('submit', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();0
//Grab Data
var that = $(this),
    url = that.attr('action'),
    method = that.attr('method'),
    data = {};

that.find('[name]').each(function(index, value) {
    var that = $(this),
        name = that.attr('name'),
        value = that.val();
    data[name] = value;

});

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: method,
    data: data,
    success: function (response) {
        console.log("Ajax Response: \"" + response + "\"");
        console.log(typeof response);
        if(response === "0"){
            document.getElementById('error_message').innerHTML = "Incorrect password";
            document.getElementById('error_message').style.color = 'red';
            document.getElementById('error_message').style.borderColor = 'red';
        }else if(response === "1"){
            window.location.href = "./index.php";
        }else if(response === "2"){
            document.getElementById('error_message').innerHTML = "Please fill all required fields.";
            document.getElementById('error_message').style.color = 'red';
        } else if(response === "3"){
            document.getElementById('error_message').innerHTML = "That username does not exist. Please try again.";
            document.getElementById('error_message').style.color = 'red';
            document.getElementById('error_message').style.borderColor = 'red';
        } else if(response === "4"){
            document.getElementById('error_message').innerHTML = "Your account has been banned on this website. Please contact an administrator.";
            document.getElementById('error_message').style.color = 'red';
            document.getElementById('error_message').style.borderColor = 'red';
        } else {
            document.getElementById('error_message').innerHTML = "Error while logging in. Please try again.<br />If you continue to recieve this error, Please contact an administrator.";
            document.getElementById('error_message').style.color = 'red';
            document.getElementById('error_message').style.borderColor = 'red';
        }
        //This is the output from the php script
   }
});

return false;
});
```

That is my current code, The output I get is

```
Ajax Response: "1"
String
```

However, It then goes straight to

```
'Error while logging in, Please contact an Administrator'
```

My question is Why is it ignoring the 'if' statements above the 'else', even though the response is '1'?

Comment: can u try response.trim() == "1" since log shows its 1 and String so may be some white space ?

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much! (I'd assumed that since I put those quotes around the string when doing "console.log" that there was no white space, But that was it. Thank you so much! (You can re-post as an answer if you'd like me to accept it)

Comment: ok I have posted the answer !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try 
`response.trim() == "1"`

since log shows its 1 and String so may be some white space is the issue.